# how to bootstrap netty channel for "slave" application

Tags: netty

I'd like to implement a netty "slave" application that listens for requests on an *outgoing* websocket connection. So on bootstrap, the application would:

1. open a ws connection to a remote server
2. listen for commands on the ws connection using a "boss" event loop
3. handle incomming commands on a "worker" event loop

My question is how to boostrap the channel - I'd rather use a bootstrap object for convenience sake (I mean vs. configuring the channel by hand), but:

1. [ServerBootstrap](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html) requires a local listening socket
2. [Bootstrap](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.html) has only one eventloop
3. [AbstractBootstrap](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/bootstrap/AbstractBootstrap.html) can't be subclassed outside of package, and ServerBootstrap/Bootstrap are final

Any suggestions on how to bootstrap the channel without duplicating a bunch of existing *Bootstrap code?

Comment: I think I not understand what you try to do and why Bootstrap does not work here.

Comment: I would like to create a (long-lived) websocket client that performs blocking actions, concurrently, based on the server's response messages.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing an EventExecutorGroup directly to the pipeline via [ChannelPipeline.html.addLast()](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html#addLast(io.netty.util.concurrent.EventExecutorGroup,%20java.lang.String,%20io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler)) - I somehow had missed that in the api docs.

From the javadocs:

```java
static final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(16);
...

ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

pipeline.addLast("decoder", new MyProtocolDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new MyProtocolEncoder());

// Tell the pipeline to run MyBusinessLogicHandler's event handler methods
// in a different thread than an I/O thread so that the I/O thread is not blocked by
// a time-consuming task.
// If your business logic is fully asynchronous or finished very quickly, you don't
// need to specify a group.
pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
```